# What does "ob" mean in a money context?

Tags: money

"Ob" appears as a sum of money in a property list of 1598, written in Latin with lots of abbreviations.
What does it mean in this context?

Comment: How about a picture?

Comment: Ditto @fdb. The answers so far are great but there's no way to give you a more definite answer without more context.

Comment: A picture would be very good indeed.

Answer (score 8):

The monetary system of an important part of medieval Europe was based on the non-decimal [*librae*, *solidi*, and *denarii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A3sd) system, (the UK only abandoned such system in 1971). A smaller subdivision of the *denarius* was the *obolus*, equivalent to half a *denarius* (or a halfpenny). This was abbreviated as *ob*. It can be found in tons of medieval documents. Meanwhile, *q* corresponds to a *quadrans*, one quarter of a *denarius*.

For example, in the [*Valor Ecclesiasticus*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OypDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PR13&lpg=PR13&dq=Valor+ecclesiasticus+temp.+Henrici+VIII+:+auctoritate+regia+institutus&source=bl&ots=UV-nvTDcwe&sig=dnSKVJuiE76Xqn9hOhQopQYzaLk&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFjpDf8qXdAhVLUhoKHermDrQQ6AEwBXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=obit&f=false), the famous survey of the finances of the Church conducted by Henry VIII, we find this monetary system:

[image]

Notice how *£*, *s.* and *d.* are written at the top of the line, with the quantity at the bottom, whereas *ob* and *q* are written directly as quantities. This is because the subdivisions within the *denarius* only need to write these symbols once. For instance, 1/4 is just *q*, 2/4 is *ob*, and 3/4 is *ob q*. In other pages you can see sometimes *ob* and *q* alone.

Other examples are [here](https://archive.org/stream/chaptersinadmini01toutuoft#page/234/search/ob) and [here](https://archive.org/details/earlyenglishcus00goog). The latter, in page 149, lists some word translations and abbreviations:

> pounds (*libre*) sterling, are written £, shillings (*solidi*) 
>   s., pence (*denarii*) d., **halfpenny (*obolus*) ob.**, farthing (*quadrans*) 
>   q., and mark (*marca*) mr.; ...

Answer (score 3):

The general meaning of *ob* is "because of" or "for". In a monetary context, I would usually take it as indicating what the money was given or received for. For instance, L&S give the example *pretium ob stultitiam*, "the price paid for stupidity".

Answer (score 2):

Possibly an obol, which came to be whatever was the smallest coin in circulation, though originally a Greek copper coin, the sixth part of a drachm, notable as the coin which accompanied the dead to pay Charon the ferryman. In my Latin dictionary as *obolus.*

The National Archive UK runs a Latin course to help those using original sources for local history.

The National Archives | Palaeography tutorial

> ‘obolus’, a Roman coin..
>   The word obolus, -i (m.) is usually abbreviated to ‘ob’.
>   ob[ol’]

Source: [The National Archives Website](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/latinpalaeography/abbreviations-lesson8.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[Ainsworth](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryenglis02ainsuoft) has a section on [abbreviations](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryenglis02ainsuoft/page/n799).

Ob *=obiit,* he died.

I'm guessing you knew that and discounted it. But the second meaning is more interesting, and only context can show if it is appropriate:

> Ob = *obryza*
>   *Obryza* vid. *obrussa*
>   *Obrussa,* (various spellings *obrisa,obrusa,obryza, etc,* uncertain etymology) (1) the test or essay for gold whether it be fine or no. (2) meton. any trial, or probation.
>   *Obryzatus,* made of the finest gold. *ex auro ad obrussam* Pliny 33.3. *aurum obryzum,* made of the finest gold, Suetonius Ner. 44